# Invalid Argument was supplied Exception when running C# test using Selenium WebDriver with Firefox 50.0

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013, firefox-marionette

I'm learning Selenium WebDriver and trying to run a simple test using Firefox 50 and Webdriver 3.0.1. I'm using Marionette driver 0.11.1

I have the following code:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"P:\Selenium Practice\FirefoxDriver", "wires.exe");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options, time);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.demoqa.com");
```

When running it, I'm getting the following exception with error code 10022:

[image]

It says:"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll"

I'm not really getting what I'm doing wrong. I went throw a lot of suggestions and none of those really worked. The last one that I describe here is that one: [Setting up Marionette/ GeckoDriver](http://automatedtester.science/marionette-geckodriver/)

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: It also says **"An invalid argument was supplied"**

Comment: Also, that page says _"At the time of writing it is still in a pre-release stage; meaning you may get unpredictable results against the current stable version of Firefox. You may want to use it with Firefox Nightly or Firefox Developer."_

Comment: Is there any solutions that I can use with my current Firefox version?

Comment: I tried that with Developer and have the same result